# ControlToValidate: how to debug?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm getting some error: ControlToValidate of '' cannot be empty (`ControlToValidate de '' ne peut pas être vide` in french).

Most of the time, this error occurs after the add of new controls in the page/user control, and it's not too difficult to figure out with control is lacking ValidationGroup.

But what can you do to find out the cause of this error when it's a legacy screen with tons of controls, with ajax and telerik components? I'm mainly looking for tips / best practices to debug such issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if you have a validator control on your page without filling in the control to validate property. It has nothing to do with validationgroups as far as I know.

To answer your question, I would say a regular expression will be the 'easiest' way to do so.

Comment: So, I have to find all the validator control in the page and remove/test them one by one?

Comment: No, assuming you've configured these in the aspx (not the code behind) you could do a regex search. If they're added dynamically I would write some debug assert statements in various places to check if any controls are in the control tree that are a validator but haven't got this property set.